# Can't get past android initial setup Wizard, after factory reset (Even after waiting over 24 hours)

Tags: factory-reset, password, setup-wizard

Currently looking for help because I am truly stumped. Device is a Galaxy J3 Emerge, it was reset to factory default settings. It seems that the password for the Google account was also reset before the factory reset. After researching online, I found out that the if the account password is reset before the factory reset is applied. You will have to wait 24 hours before attempting to sign in again.

So I sat the phone down after reading the message about waiting 24 hours. I left it there for 4 days. Got the error on Sunday, went to work for the entire week and tried again on Thursday. The same message is displayed! Reboot and tried again, still the same message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont know if you found an answer yet or not, but i had the same problem with a galaxy player 5.0. Not sure if your solution would be much different, but I downloaded Odin, and flashed the software, and it works perfectly now.